# Using a RewriteRule to IP restrict and serve specific file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, drupal, url-rewriting

I'm trying to restrict access to dev/test environments of an Acquia Drupal site based on a range of allowed IPs. I've simplified my example below to just a single IP (192.168.1.2). If you are not in the range, I want to serve you block.txt. If you are in the range, the rule should not apply. The rule seems to be working correctly when accessing the site from an IP not in the range - it serves block.txt. The problem is when accessing it from an IP in the allowed range, Apache serves a simple 404 saying "File not found" instead of just serving the site. Any ideas?

```
SetEnvIf AH_Client_IP ^192\.168\.1\.2$ allowed-ip

RewriteCond %{ENV:allowed-ip} !=1
RewriteCond %{ENV:AH_SITE_ENVIRONMENT} ^(dev|test)$
RewriteRule ^ block.txt [L]
```

**Note**: this code is right after `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> RewriteEngine on`